# Square Wire Service Implementation

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, square-wire

I'm trying to learn about grpc and protocol buffers while creating a test app using square's wire library. I've got to the point of generating both client and server files but I got stuck in creating a server side app. The documentation is too simple and the examples in the library have to much going on.

Can anyone point out what are the next steps after generating the files?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language your are using, but each gRPC language has similar set of examples. For example, for a simple server-side app, you can find the Python example at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/greeter_server.py